# Bash tabcomplete file names for environmental variable values

Tags: bash, autocomplete

After I upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04, bash would no longer let me tabcomplete file names when setting the value of an environmental variable, e.g.

```
FILE=/home/_
```

`_` is where I would press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

How can I get tabcompleting of filenames in env variables back?

My bash version is 4.3.11.

Comment: Does TAB work as usual for stuff other than setting variables?

Comment: Post the content of your `.bashrc`. Are you using programmable completion (is `/etc/bash_completion` read on startup)?

Comment: @jim Yes, otherwise the tab works ok. Actually, it even works with the code snippet in the original post, but not if I try to enter a command, e.g. `some_command FILE=/home/` doesn't work. Before it used to work also with commands.

@Gilles: My .bashrc is unedited Ubuntu 14.04 .bashrc. I am not using programmable completion.